# jQuery: Access JSON through dynamic variables and save results in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, variables, dynamic

I'm creating a gallery website with several categories and a selection of items in every category.

The plan is to generate two variables that hold the current category (`currentCategory`) and the current item (`currentItem`), tell jQuery to look for that category in the JSON file, fetch the data the current item and store everything in a jQuery array (`currentContent`). From there I would just access the jQuery array when necessary, call the required position inside the array and load the data into the DOM.

My problem is ... well, everything. I don't how to access JSON through a dynamic variable let alone store the fetched data in an array. I've read many, many, maaaany tutorials and discussions, but I can't even recognize which tutorial or discussion might be relevant for my problem, let alone apply that knowledge to my problem.

Here is my JSON file (so far only with one category):

```
{
    "websites": [
        {
            "title": "Chains of Honor for 'Joomla'",
            "code": "chains",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Agar Teryn - Book of Tales",
            "code": "agar",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Minifolio for 'The Secretary'",
            "code": "minifolio",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Mirogreen for 'Wordpress'",
            "code": "mirogreen",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Lain Ardhon for 'phpBB3'",
            "code": "ardhon",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the little bit of jQuery I have:

```
function getContent(currentItem,currentCategory,currentContent) {
    $.getJSON('repository.json', function(data) {  
        global.currentContent = data.websites[currentItem];
        console.log(global.currentContent);
    });
};
```

It's easy when you call the required JSON array by name (`data.websites`), but what I need and what I was hoping for is that it would be as easy as just using `data.variable[position]` to get the data stored behind the selected item in the current category.

And before I forget: How do I call a position inside a jQuery array? I thought you could do that with `array[integer]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're looking for? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/g8A5Q/)

JS

```
mystuff =
{
    "websites": [
        {
            "title": "Chains of Honor for 'Joomla'",
            "code": "chains",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Agar Teryn - Book of Tales",
            "code": "agar",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Minifolio for 'The Secretary'",
            "code": "minifolio",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Mirogreen for 'Wordpress'",
            "code": "mirogreen",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Lain Ardhon for 'phpBB3'",
            "code": "ardhon",
            "desc": "Some sample text to explain what's going on",
            "items": "3"
        }
    ]
};
$('#selectme, #wordme').change(function(){
   firstnumber = $('#selectme').val();
   firstname = $('#wordme').val();
   var mytest = 'mystuff.websites[' + firstnumber + '].' + firstname;
   $('.putmehere').html( eval(mytest) );

});
```

---

Edit:
1. Don't think of 'jQuery', but just think of javascript (JavaScript Object Notation).

1. The highest "level" is the name of the variable, thus all of your methods of access in this case should start with 'mystuff.'.
2. The next lower level is the word before the ': [' - thus after the highest level you put 'websites.' - So mystuff.websites.
3. It then gets interesting for 'websites', there are a whole series of {}, and each of those has a "number" starting with zero - so you need to pick a number that corresponds to the number of the '{}' - .websites[x]. Specific example 'mystuff.websites[0]' refers to the first set of bracketed values.
4. The in each set of brackets '{}' there is a "name" and a "value" - "title": "lain Ardhon for 'phpBB3'". So you choose a 'name',  and therefore your value is defined. Specific example 'mystuff.websites[0].code' = "chains"

I've set up the attached fiddle to allow you to look at the complete array (the array must always come before your code that accesses the array), then you can select the 'number' of the {}'s and the 'name' of the variable.

Comment: Thank you for help.

What I do is that when you choose an item from a category, jquery looks at the corresponding list to get the current category and indexes (?) the link that was clicked from that list. 

For example the use could pick item "5" from the list "photography". The variables "currentCategory" and "currentItem" then carry the information "photography" and "5".
What I want to do now is to tell jquery to look for category "photography" in the JSON-file, fetch the data that is stored for "fifth" item and save everything in an array.

Comment: Just to make that clear: There will be more datasets than just "websites" in the JSON-file, for example "photography", "logotypes" or "digital art". What if the user choses an item from the list "logotypes"? Obviously "mystuff.websites[0]" won't work there. I need something dynamic at that point. That's my first problem. The second is to store the JSON-date (title, desc, code, items) in a global array. I need some of that data more than once, so I thought it would be better and easier to store everything in an array instead of accessing JSON every time when I need to build content.

Comment: Like I said, I've read many discussions on how to work with dynamic referers at that point and store JSON-stuff in an jquery-array. I hzst can't get my head around how to apply that stuff to my project. So please bear with me if I act like a complete idiot. If there was a tutorial that wouldn't stop with fetching "Hello World!" from JSON and writing it into a div-container, and that was still understandble for newbies, I would use that instead of stealing your time (I have already wasted two days on this and still have no idea, what I'm doing).

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/P6aL8/ - and play with the variables at the bottom and see what you learn about accessing the array.

Comment: I understand how to access JSON-data through a fix string value like "mystuff.websites[]". I need to know how to access that data with a dynamic string value like "mystuff.dynamicString[]".

Comment: Look at my first fiddle at the bottom. You create a string like this -    var mytest = 'mystuff.websites[' + firstnumber + '].' + firstname; - then to "call" the data you must use the "eval()" function - arraydata = eval('mystuff.websites[' + firstnumber + '].' + firstname;)

Comment: I understand that, but it's not what I need. As far as I understand it that solution would be static. What I need is a dynamic solution. What if the user selects an item from the category "photography"? You don't want me to write the same code for every category, right?

Comment: I'm slowly realizing though, that it might be easier to work with a multidmensional array (something like "gallery[categories[items]]"). Istead of storing the current category as string, I'd store it as index. I could then simply iterate through something like "data.gallery[2][3]" and push the fetched data into an array. That should be no problem, right? Or what that considered to be bad practice?

Comment: Only downside I see with that is that I'd lose my IDs (websites, logotypes, photography and so on). I find it easier to work with IDs instead of integers. On the other hand, that should be well in the spirit of the divison between content, structure, design and functionality since no content would "drip" into my javascript anymore.

Comment: That's what I tried to show you with my first fiddle. Select from a drop-down and then a number and up pops a variable. I think you need to clarify in your own mind exactly what you want. "There will be six categories, their names are x, y, z...", "under categories there will be 3 types, a, b, c..." "The user selects from x...blah blah blah" Then setting up the array and accessing it is straight-forward.

Comment: What has confused me is that you were using code of which I knew that it doesn't work for what I needed. The website will have five or six categories/lists. Each category/list has something between six and twelve elements (work examples). The user picks a random element from a random list. What I need is a dynamic code that translates that selection into something that jquery can use to look for the requested data in the JSON-file. Translating the user selection is easy. It's the part where jquery has to look for the selected element and save it to an array that is creating nightmares for me.

Comment: Oh my god, it's so easy. It never occured to me that I could just write everything in "plain text" and then use "eval()" to execute the expression, although you have pointed me in that direction several times. I'm sorry that I have wasted your time. I have wasted so much time on this that I simply couldn't see the answer. Next step: Pushing everything in an array. Tomorrow.

Comment: currentContent = 'data.' + currentCategory + '[' + currentItem + ']'; *sigh* I feel so stupid now. Happy but stupid.